# Inline stretchy button with CSS background image

Tags: css, button, rounded-corners, stretch

Anyone know if there's a bullet-proof (standards-compliant to XHTML1.1 strict, cross-browser, non-javascript) way to use CSS and background images to turn an **inline**  link into a visual button that will stretch to accommodate different amounts of text (or text resizing)?

I'm thinking I need to use background images as the designer's buttons have rounded corners with a different coloured border. It must work in IE6 (Government job).

Im pretty sure the answer is no, but as always thought it worth a check.

Amongst other things, I've already tried variations on the [sliding doors technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/), but can't make it work as the solution needs to work inline (i.e. within a paragraph) and I can't set a fixed width.

EDIT: There are several buttons, each of which has a different colour for foreground, border and background. They also have a gradient 'face', but no need for transparency or anything else 'unorthodox'. Unfortunately I can't link to examples as I'm under an NDA.

Comment: You could save a lot of confusion if you actually linked to what the button should look like, and how it should stretch, if there's any opacity involved, transparency, unorthodox bits.

Comment: Apologies if I've created any confusion. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will fit your needs, but I helped someone with hoverable rounded buttons in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418766/changing-color-of-rounded-corners-button-with-css/1448762#1448762)... it uses only HTML and CSS.

Comment: It doesn't directly, but I followed a link from your post to find my answer so +1 Cheers :)

Comment: Hehe, so you found the links I posted there as well ;) Glad you got your answer :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this within your restrictions.  The problem is that you have *one* element, but to properly do stretching, you need *three* (unstretched left side, stretched center, unstretched right side).

Comment: Good advice (cheers), but I've managed to do it with a single span within an anchor. I'm going to answer my own question in case anyone else needs to do it.

Comment: Ah.  So you did it with two elements instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you probably need to make [image buttons](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/using_an_image_as_a_submit_button.php3) for this.

Comment: Thanks but that won't work as a form within a paragraph won't validate.

Comment: ...plus the method you've linked to uses Javascript.

Comment: It only needs JavaScript if you're trying to attach event handlers or funky hover effects. Can you put the form surrounding the paragraph?

Comment: But it's fixed size. I need the button to be able to stretch.

Comment: You can use the image to repeat-x

then set the <a> to have a min-height of X amount of pixels. It will expand with the letter size and not get smaller then your specified width.

Comment: I can't just set the image to repeat 'cos of the rounded corners - that's why I went down the 'sliding doors' path in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside in future, [here's a page on CSS button styling](http://www.narga.net/beautiful-and-simple-css-button-styling/).