# cross browser strechable round corner with semantic code and minimal use of images. is it possible?

Tags: css, xhtml

I know to make round corner is not possible for IE without Javascript or images. 
JS solution will not work if js is disabled so i want to go for image option

i need any images + css solution to make cross browser compatible round corner div with **minimal** ,**easy to make** and pure **semantic** and **W3C valid** code, **strechable** and **minimal use of images** and photoshop effort.

I know about FF and safari can do with pure css but i need cross browser solution without javascript. I want to make with minimal use of XHTML code and images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote about this a few years ago: semantic HTML, one image, minimal CSS, works in most browsers. Combines several techniques.

http://www.the-haystack.com/2006/03/16/rounded-corners/

Still, I would go for `(-[prefix]-)border-radius` in browsers that support it, and leave the other browsers as they are.

Comment: looking intresting . can u share psd of this image

Comment: I don't have the PSD anymore. This was three years ago.

Answer (score 3):

See [25 Rounded Corners Techniques with CSS](http://www.cssjuice.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/).

> [ThrashBox](http://www.vertexwerks.com/tests/sidebox/) - create rounded-corner boxes with visual flare and the absolute minimal amount of semantically correct markup.

[image]
<sub>(source: [cssjuice.com](http://cssjuice.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/the-thrashbox.png))</sub>

The XHTML:

```
<div class="sidebox">
    <div class="boxhead"><h2>Test Headline</h2></div>
    <div class="boxbody">
        <p>This is a short sample paragraph.</p>
        <p>And another one.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

> [Resizable box with freely stylable corners and surface](http://roundedbox.andreas-kalt.de/) - resizable rounded corners box.

[image]
<sub>(source: [cssjuice.com](http://cssjuice.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/stylable-box_1185588162107.png))</sub>

Both authors mention [Sliding Doors of CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) about strechability.

Comment: If you don't specify the width for the top div, the box seems to stretch up until certain point. See the credit box on the ThrashBox page.

Comment: I'd rather look at the url above and choose the one that suits my needs. However IMHO you'll always end up using photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do something like this

```
<div id="box">
    <p>content</p>
    <span class="top-left"></span>
    <span class="top-right"></span>
    <span class="bottom-left"></span>
    <span class="bottom-right"></span>
</div>
```

And position the `span`s in the corners with absolute positioning. It's got a bit of pollution with the `span`s, but it will work cross browser. You may be able to get rid of one too, and just made the `#box` background one of the corner images.

Please make use of sprites too. Draw a circle, and use negative background positions to position a quadrant into each span.

If you wanted to be as semantic (and a little different) as possible, you could wrap all those `span`s in an IE conditional comment, apply border-radius to the box, and then apply the styles for the spans for our friend IE. This however would seem to me like a bit of overkill.

Answer (score 1):

This site has a lot of "[snazzy borders](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/snazzy2.html)" and "[krazy korners](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/krazy.html)", Stu rocks!

Also you weren't specific in your question about boxes or buttons, so you can check out these links for some CSS methods:

An SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418766/changing-color-of-rounded-corners-button-with-css/1448762#1448762) and some links: [Sexy buttons](http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html) and [unbreakable buttons](http://webdev.stephband.info/buttons/)